# How Spike Arrest and Quota policy works parallelly in ApiGee?

Tags: apigee

I am investigating one issue related to the rate limiting in my server. Previous developer has setup spike arrest and quota policy in ApiGee. I read the documentation but I am unable to understand how both the policy works parallelly?

For example:

Client (Web, Mobile) calling the API. There are more than 100 concurrent users access the API. So which policy applied? Spike arrest or Quota?

If anyone has real world idea about this then please provide some insight.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The particular behavior of the API proxy will depend on the placement of the two policies within flows, but assuming a standard request flow with serial policies, then generally the [spike-arrest policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/spike-arrest-policy) will protect your back-end services *in aggregate*, while the [quota policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/quota-policy) will enforce rate-limits on some chosen *client-specific criteria*. Thus one is a general overall safety protection for your business-logic back-end (spike arrest), and the other is more for enforcing client-specific constraints as dictated by your end-to-end application design and expected use-case interactions (quota). Both are configurable though, so the details of those configurations matter in the final analysis.

Comparison docs are here: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/develop/comparing-quota-spike-arrest-and-concurrent-rate-limit-policies

Comment: Thanks @evensche. As now we have default configuration for spike arrest and quota policy. There is no configuration for specific to client in quote policy configuration. So in this case which policy in general will apply?

Comment: The default spike-arrest policy is 30 calls/sec:
`<Rate>30ps</Rate>`

and the default Quota policy has no specified `<Identifier>` with which to differentiate clients from one another, so it generalizes, using, by default, simply:
`<Allow count="2000" countRef="request.header.allowed_quota"/>`
`<Interval ref="request.header.quota_count">1</Interval>`
`<TimeUnit ref="request.header.quota_timeout">month</TimeUnit>`

... which is a limit of 2000 API calls/month. 

Net-net: Calls metered as /second and /month are quite different. Constraints may be enforced independently based on rate.